# How to redirect 301 with dynamically generated URL while removing a slash?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been at this all day long, tried dozens of variations but can't quite seem to get this rewrite to work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pwreset\.php\ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/support\/pwreset\.php [L]
```

The URL it returns is:

```
https://www.web-jive.com/support/pwreset.php/?key=cdc3b1aa842785f7345be501a30ddc83
```

What I need to be removed is the pwrest.php trailing slash before the question mark. Where am I going wrong on this?

The idea is to have the first URL below, redirect to the second:

```
https://example1.com/pwreset.php?key=cdc3b1aa842785f7345be501a30ddc83

https://example2.com/support/pwreset.php?key=cdc3b1aa842785f7345be501a30ddc83
```

EDIT

Per Mr. White's suggestion, I'm posting the whole .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Announcements
RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]

# Downloads
RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^downloads$ ./downloads.php [L,NC]

# Knowledgebase
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase$ ./knowledgebase.php [L,NC]

#Password reset
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=[0-9a-f]{32}$
RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ https://www.web-jive.com/support%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

#Redirect to new support URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members\.web\-jive\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.members\.web\-jive\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.web\-jive\.com\/support" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members\.web\-jive\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.members\.web\-jive\.com$
```

Comment: "...while removing a slash" - The issue here is that there is no slash in your source URL to remove? And your _substitution_ string (target URL) does not contain this additional slash. So where is this additional slash coming from?

Comment: I have no clue as to where that extra slash is coming from. It's not present in the source URL so why is it showing in the rewritten URL?  That's what I've been trying to figure out.

Comment: Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question.

Comment: Done :)  Full htaccess added

Comment: You sent me down the rabbit hole and the target site is rewriting the rule, not the source! Now I have to figure out on the target site, why it's rewriting URL's to start with (WP site).

Comment: In that case, you should be seeing multiple redirects in the network traffic. The first one from _this_ site, without a traling slash, and a second one _with_ a trailing slash, after being redirected to the target site. Do this URL map to a physical file at the target site? Otherwise, WP shouldn't be doing anything with it, unless there is a plugin that is doing this?

Comment: Figured it out!  The rewrite Mr. White added is the working rewrite. What I wasn't suspecting was the target site rewriting the URL once it hit there. The target site is adding the additional slash in a WP plugin. No to track down that developer for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are seeing (with the trailing slash on the URL-path) isn't the result of just the directives you posted, so maybe you have a conflict with other directives or you are seeing a cached response.

However, the rule you posted would seem to be far more complex than it needs to be.

> ```
> 1. https://example1.com/pwreset.php?key=cdc3b1aa842785f7345be501a30ddc83
> 2. https://example2.com/support/pwreset.php?key=cdc3b1aa842785f7345be501a30ddc83
> ```

Assumptions:

- You don't need to match the `key` value; just the URL-path (ie. `/pwreset.php`)
- `example1.com` and `example2.com` point to different places (the filesystem does not overlap).

To redirect from `1.` to `2.` try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the root of `example1.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ https://example2.com/support%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Any query string (eg. `key=abc...`) is passed through unaltered.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) when you have confirmed it works OK.

---

If you need to check that a `key=` URL param is present and is set to a 32 hex string (which appears to be what your example represents) then include a condition before the above `RewriteRule` that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=[0-9a-f]{32}$
RewriteRule ^pwreset\.php$ https://example2.com/support%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

If any other URL params are present on the request then the redirect will fail.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/support\/pwreset\.php [L]
> ```

This looks very cPanel-esque. There is no need to backslash colons, slashes and dots in the `RewriteRule` *susbtitution* argument. This is an "ordinary" string, not a regex. These characters have no special meaning here.

Comment: Your first example is giving me the Too many redirects error in Chrome. The second example works but has the / still trailing the string. That's what's been dogging me, that slash. Any more thoughts on this?  I have also moved this query to the top of .htaccess to be evaluated first, same challenge.

Comment: There must be "something else" going on here. Please edit your question to include your entire `.htaccess` file. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? What you describe is impossible given only these directives. These two examples are really "the same" - so your statement that the first one results in a redirect loop and the second one "works" but appends a slash, doesn't really make any sense? (Given the example URL in your question, the result of both directives are identical.) As mentioned above, I'm assuming `example1.com` and `example2.com` point to different filesystems?